# Ecrypt/decrypt with CryptoStream

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt streams using CryptoStream (Aes). These are the method I'm using:

```
public void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();

        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //aes.BlockSize = 128;

        ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(output, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            input.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            //cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cryptoStream.Flush();
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

end

```
public void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();

        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //aes.BlockSize = 128;

        ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();

        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(input, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            cryptoStream.CopyTo(output);
            cryptoStream.Flush();
            cryptoStream.Close();            }
    }
```

What I'm doing:

- I generate a random text file. It has several lines, and the last one is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_0987654321"
- I encrypt the file using the Encrypt method, passing FileStream(s) in input and output.
- I decrypt the result using the Decrypt method, passing FileStream(s) in input and output.

What I obtain are files with the last line not equal (compared using the old but gold WinMerge): the original file, as I wrote, has the "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_0987654321" line, while the result file has "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ_1234567890_0987" (note that six final characters are missing).

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you remember to `Flush()`/`Close()` the `output` file stream before checking the file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if you are saying to Flush() and Close() the CryptoStream, yes, I did, but no result. I edited the question.

Comment: No, at the call site (the code that calls `Decrypt()`) - you're passing `Stream output` as a parameter to the function, what do you do with that stream object after `Decrypt()` returns?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Oh, now I understand. Thank you for the suggestion! Following the working code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mathias R. Jassen for the suggestion. Following the working code:

```
public void Encrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();

        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //aes.BlockSize = 128;

        ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(output, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            input.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
    }
```

and

```
public void Decrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();

        aes.Key = Key;
        aes.IV = IV;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //aes.BlockSize = 128;

        ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();

        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(input, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            cryptoStream.CopyTo(output);
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }
        output.Flush();
    }
```

Please, note the

```
output.Flush()
```

command!

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to close/flush? That should in general be taken care of when the streams are disposed.

Comment: @JonasH I don't know why (...and I have no time to check...), but if I don't use the Flush() command the result is not correct. I read the doc and it should work as you write, but at the end of the day, it doesn't...